# What is the way in which we import Map?

Tags: android

Whenever I import *com.android.maps.MapActivity* it gives an error as "*cant resolve the class*".

Comment: Try adding a JAR containing that class to your CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

use the below link for display a map.It is one of the best example for displaying map
 [Display a google map](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the map library to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

And you need to select the Google API as a project build target and not the "Android Open Source Project"

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have set the target to be `Google-APIs-<version>` for using maps, and not just `Android` APIs.

Since Maps are a part of Google APIs